# Jenkins parallel contains multiple stages internally

Tags: jenkins, parallel-processing, jenkins-pipeline

```
def run(service) {
    task = {
        def thing = null
        waitUntil {
            thing = latch.pollFirst();
            return thing != null;
        }
        try {
            stage("${service}") {
                withEnv(["service=${service}"]){
                    stages {
                        stage('1') {
                            script {
                                sh """
                                    sleep 6
                                """
                            }
                        }
                        stage('2') {
                            script {
                                sh """
                                    sleep 6
                                """
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            latch.offer(thing)
        }        
    }
  return task
}

pipeline {
    agent {
        label "74"
    }

    options {
      timestamps()
    }

    stages {
        stage("Pipeline") {
            steps {
                script {
                    def task = [:]
                    MAX_CONCURRENT = 1
                    latch = new java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque(MAX_CONCURRENT)
                    for(int i=0; i<MAX_CONCURRENT; i++)
                        latch.offer("$i")
                    // for (service in model_list.tokenize('\n')){
                    final foundFiles = sh(script: 'ls -1 post', returnStdout: true).split()
                    for (service in foundFiles){
                        task[service] = run(service)
                    }
                    
                    parallel task
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Above code，I want to create as many satges based on how many files are in the folder, and then there will be multiple satges in a separate stage
But I got an error，**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'stages' found among steps**

```
def run(service) {
    task = {
        def thing = null
        waitUntil {
            thing = latch.pollFirst();
            return thing != null;
        }
        try {
            stage("${service}") {
                withEnv(["service=${service}"]){
                    script {
                        sh """
                            ls ${service}
                        """
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            latch.offer(thing)
        }        
    }
  return task
}
```

I can execute it, but for each Satge, there is only one Satge,
Now I want to have multiple Satges in each Satge, but I don't know what to do

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    node('228') {
        stage("${service}") {
            withEnv(["service=${service}"]){
                stage('run') {
                    script {
                        sh """
                            sleep 6
                        """
                    }
                }
                stage('analysis') {
                    script {
                        catchError(buildResult: 'FAILURE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                            sh """
                                sleep 6
                            """
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ok,I solved it, you can do this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).